# Create File object of file from parent directory in java

Tags: java, io

I have this issue of accessing a file in one of the parent directories.
To explain, consider the following dir structure:-

```
C:/Workspace/Appl/src/org/abc/bm/TestFile.xml  
C:/Workspace/Appl/src/org/abc/bm/tests/CheckTest.java
```

In the CheckTest.java I want to create a File instance for the TestFile.xml

```
public class Check {
    public void checkMethod() {
        File f = new File({filePath value I want to determine}, "TestFile.xml");
    }
}
```

I tried a few things with `getAbsolutePath()` and the `getParent()` etc but was getting a bit complicated and frankly I think I messed it up.
The reason I don't want to use `"C:/Workspace/Appl/src/org/abc/bm"` while creating the `File` instance is because the `C:/Workspace/Appl` is not fixed and in all circumstances will be different at runtime and basically I don't want to hard-code.
What could be the easiest and cleaner way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load it from Classpath in this case.

In your CheckTest.java, try

```
FileInputStream fileIs = new FileInputStream(CheckTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("org/abc/bm/TestFile.xml");
```

Comment: @Andrew Thompson @Nishan - 
I have now tried both these and they work. Any particular advantage/dis-advantage using either one way?

Comment: Each of these rely on one basic principle - to load from classpath. So, any one of them should be good for you, rather than loading directly from a hardcoded file path.

Comment: But if all you want to do is to read the file, you don't need to create the File object in the first place. Just go with the `FileInputStream` approach that I have indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.getProperty to get the base dir or you set the base.dir during application launch

```
java -Dbase.dir=c:\User\pkg 

System.getProperty("base.dir");
```

and use

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the easiest and cleaner way to achieve this ?

For accessing static resources use:

```
URL urlToResource = this.getClasS().getResource("path/to/the.resource");
```

If the resource is expected to change, write it to a sub-directory of user.home, where it is easy to locate later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't get a reference to the source file path on runtime.

But, you can access the resrources included at your classpath (where you complied .class files will be).

Normally, your compiler will copy the xml file included at your srouce directory into the build directory, so at last, you could end up having something like this:

```
C:/Workspace/Appl/classes/org/abc/bm/TestFile.xml  
C:/Workspace/Appl/classes/org/abc/bm/tests/CheckTest.class
```

Then, with your classpath pointing to the compiled classes root dir, you get the resources from this directory, using the [ClassLoader.getResource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method (or the equivalent [Class.getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method).

```
public class Check {
    public void checkMethod() {
        java.net.URL fileURL=this.getClass().getResource("/org/abc/bm/tests/TestFile.xml");

        File f=new File( fileURL.toURI());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could do this:

```
String pathOfTheCurrentClass = this.getClass().getResource(".").getPath();        
File file = new File(pathOfTheCurrentClass + "/..", "Testfile.xml");
```

or

```
String pathOfTheCurrentClass = this.getClass().getResource(".").getPath();
File filePath = new File(pathOfTheCurrentClass);
File file = new File(filePath.getParent(), "Testfile.xml");
```

But as Tomas Naros points out this gives you the file located in the build path.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try

```
URL some=Test.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/abc/bm/TestFile.xml");
File file = new File(some.getFile());
```

Comment: This will fail, as getFile only returns the name of the file, not the File object itself

Comment: If you do Test.class.getClass().getclassLoader(), you'll get the class loader of the java.lang.Class object and not Test's.

Comment: Well forgot to mention earlier, I tried this way using `this.getClass()` and that how it worked.